# How to delete certain rows of excel data from python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlrd

So I have a lot of data, and I want to get rid of certain data. I want to get rid of the data that does not have values in column M and/or N. How should I go about this?

Have a look at some of my excel data:

[image]

As you can see, there are some rows that do not have any values for M and/or N, so I would like to get rid of them.

Thanks